# Check if each line from a text file contains a certain string, and add the ones that do to a listbox?

Tags: vb.net

The following code works, to simply get each line as a line in the listbox.

```
Reader = IO.File.OpenText(textlocation)
Dim bookmarks() As String = Reader.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do Until i = bookmarks.Length
  lstFavorites.Items.Add(bookmarks(i))
  i += 1
Loop
```

But I don't want every line to go into the text box. I only want the lines that contain the text "Bookmark" to go into the listbox. What can I do to achieve this? I've tried everything I can think of.

Heres some code I tried, I can't see the problem in it, but it seems to just crash my program.

```
Do Until i = bookmarks.Length
  If bookmarks(i).Contains("at") Then
    If radBookmarks.Checked Then
      If bookmarks(i).Contains("Bookmark") Then
        Original = bookmarks(i)
        BeginningOfDemoName = Original.Substring(Original.LastIndexOf("(") + 2)
        TickWithParenthesis = BeginningOfDemoName.Substring(BeginningOfDemoName.IndexOf(Chr(34)) + 4)
        Tick = TickWithParenthesis.Split(" ")(1).Split(")")(0)
        DemoName = BeginningOfDemoName.Split(Chr(34))(0)
        ToList = DemoName + " at " + Tick
        lstFavorites.Items.Add(ToList)
        i += 1
      Else
        i += 1
      End If
    ElseIf radEverything.Checked Then
      Original = bookmarks(i)
      BeginningOfDemoName = Original.Substring(Original.LastIndexOf("(") + 2)
      TickWithParenthesis = BeginningOfDemoName.Substring(BeginningOfDemoName.IndexOf(Chr(34)) + 4)
      Tick = TickWithParenthesis.Split(" ")(1).Split(")")(0)
      DemoName = BeginningOfDemoName.Split(Chr(34))(0)
      ToList = DemoName + " at " + Tick

      lstFavorites.Items.Add(ToList)
      i += 1
    End If
  End If
Loop
```

Comment: In your code there are many assumptions that could not be true. What happen for example if one of your strings doesn't contains an open parenthesys?. You don't check the result of `LastIndexOf`. Like this one, in other parts of your code, you take for granted that a certain operation doesn't fail and pass its result as input for another operation.

Comment: By the way, could you add some sample text that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Every line looks like this:

Comment: [2013/01/15/ 21:45] Kill Streak:4 ("cp_badlands_RED_BLU_01152013_2142" at 10656)

Comment: [2013/01/19/ 18:00] Player bookmark ("cp_badlands_RED_BLU_01192013_1746" at 55811)

Comment: Each line of the text file, when ran through those few lines of code, will come out with the desired final string. The problem is they're not making it to the list box

Comment: I normalized spaces in your code. Now you can clearly see it needs refactoring. Try to eliminate two identical pieces of code in different logical branches, and make one.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, it made me notice that I did not increase the integer by 1 if the string did not have " at " in it (meaning it was a blank line). I simply added Else i += 1 before the last 'End If' and now it's working flawlessly. Your removing of spaces helped me look at it differently and realize that. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
 If bookmarks(i).Contains("Bookmark") Then
```

to

```
 If bookmarks(i).IndexOf("Bookmark", 
                 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
```

Contains do a case sensitive comparison and your input string contains a lower case 'bookmark'

Comment: So, at the end of the loop, if you check lstFavorites.Items.Count you get zero?

Comment: It doesn't even get to the end of the loop before crashing. Not an exception crash or anything. It just becomes unresponsive.